# How can my OS X app accept drag-and-drop of picture files from Desk in Cocoa?

Tags: swift

I got an error when I drag files to my macOS app,
`[sandbox] Failed to get a sandbox extension`，when i set `App Sandbox`value boolean no,it is ok,but i want put my app to appstore,I must set `App Sandbox` YES, how can I do?

```
class FYOpenDragFileView: NSView{

override func draggingEnded(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) {
        print("松手了")
        setupWithActive(active: false)
    }
    override func draggingExited(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        isDraging = false
        setupWithActive(active: false)
        print("draggingExited 进去又出来")
    }
    override func updateDraggingItemsForDrag(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        guard let next = delegate else {
            return;
        }
        next.fileDraging()
        print("更新拖动文件")
    }
    override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {

        guard let items = sender.draggingPasteboard.pasteboardItems else{
            return false
        }
        var datas = [Data]()
        for i in 0..<items.count{


            let item = items[i] .string(forType: .fileURL)
            if item != nil {
// this have an error 
//[sandbox] Failed to get a sandbox extension
                let da = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: item!)!)
                guard let next = da else {
                    continue
                }
                datas.append(next)
            }
        }
        QiniuUploadManger.uploadImage(nil, data: datas)
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: `URL(string:` is the wrong API for file system URLs anyway. You have to use `URL(fileURLWithPath:`

Comment: `let da = try? Data(contentsOf : URL(fileURLWithPath: item!))` it does not works for me. Xcode Version 11.2.1 (11B500),macOS  10.14.6 (18G87)

Comment: but when I set  no value key App Sanbox  in `entitlements`,it works for me,but when I packet ipa to AppStore ,it is error something

Answer (score 0):

With sandboxing, you'll have to set the appropriate "entitlements" for your app to receive drag-&-dropped files, which is probably why you're getting this error.

The entitlements file should already have been generated for you when you enabled Sandboxing. See this [Apple documentation for details](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW6).

Comment: I did add this to`entitlements`,still bad